# CircuitMaker generates outlines for internal resistors

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, circuitmaker

CircuitMaker is generating outlines for internal resistors and I think the manufacture will cut holes in those places.

The PCB view (top layer) is:
[image]

The problems are resistors R4, R5, and R1.

The outline is below:

[image]

See the red cicles that mark the resistors. Why is that outline generated?

Finally, I have used ViewMate to verify the outline Gerber file:

[image]

As you can see, the three resistors are outlined. Does this mean the manufacturer will make holes in those 3 rectangles?

I have tried to select these rectangles and delete them, but I cannot select them. I certainly haven't added them myself.

What can I do?

Comment: Depends on the PCB-Service you will use. Of course, best would be to remove the outline of the resistors. But: If you write a comment/email to your service, they will be happy to just not route them.

Comment: maybe the hole is to allow the resistor to have a lower profile when assembled onto the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing to a different resistor with a similar footprint.